# $dg_y$ carries a subspace of $T_y(Y)$ onto $\mathbb{R}^l$

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology

The question arises from Guillemin and Pallack Page 28 above the frame:

> $dg_y$ carries a subspace of $T_y(Y)$ onto $\mathbb{R}^l$ precisely if that subspace and $T_y(Z)$ span all of $T_y(Y)$.

I understand the kernel of $dg_y$ is $T_y(Y)$, but I think $dg_y$ carries a subspace of $T_y(Y)$ onto $\mathbb{R}^l$ precisely if that **subspace** span all of $T_y(Y)$? Because all $T_y(Z)$ goes to 0 in $\mathbb{R}^l$, which already hit by the kernel of the subspace.....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This boils down to pure linear algebra.

**Claim:**  If $f:V \to W$ is a surjective linear map with kernel $K$, and $U$ is a subspace of $V$, then
$$
f(U) = W \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad U + K = V.
$$

*Proof.*  If $U + K = V$, then $f(U) = f(U + K) = f(V) = W$, as $f$ is surjective.  For the converse, since $U + K \leq V$, it suffices to show that the dimensions match.  Since
$$
\begin{align}
\ker f \big|_{U + K} &= \ker f \cap (U + K) \\
&= K \cap (U + K) \\
&= K,
\end{align}
$$
the rank-nullity theorem gives,
$$
\begin{align}
\dim V &= \dim W + \dim K \\
&= \dim f(U) + \dim K \\
&= \dim f(U + K) + \dim \ker f \big|_{U + K} \\
&= \dim (U + K).
\end{align}
$$

---

Now, put $V = T_y(Y)$, $W = \Bbb{R}^\ell$, and $f = dg_y$ with $K = T_y(Z)$.